# Am I doing indexes for my MySQL table right?

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-performance

I have a MySQL table that has a list of messages, where each message belongs to a room. I do queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE room='offtopic' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

As my table has increased to the number of hundreds of thousands of messages, the DB is becoming a bit slow. I added a index called `room`, BTREE, not unique, not packed, column room(5), and now with a cardinality of 425.

Will this help performance? Aka am I doing it right?

Comment: An index on room and id are sufficient in that case. Use [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) to see which indices will be used in a query. (If you're already added the index then, is the query still slow? If so, what is the EXPLAIN on the particular query and result-set size?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's almost certainly a good idea for *that* particular query, can't say for other queries since you haven't shown them.

By adding an index on the `room` column, it should be able to far more efficiently discount a large proportion of the table early in the process, using the index to throw away every row where the room is not what you want. A cardinality of 425 (which is usually an estimate) means that there are that many unique values in the index so that becomes your starting point (400-odd rows) rather than the hundreds of thousands you mentioned.

But the basic idea is to run queries in a production-like environment to see how they perform (by using [`explain`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/execution-plan-information.html)), *then* add the index and try again to see what sort of improvement you get.

Optimisation is a fool's errand without measurement. The best mantra I've ever heard on the subject is *"measure, don't guess".*

Comment: I dropped the index, the query executed faster??

Comment: @gladoscc, then that needs investigating. That's a useful effect of measuring rather than guessing. You may find it turns out to be a simple aberration but you should look into it, including asking another question if need be.